# How to know that the application is launched by debugger (VisualStudio) C#

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

In my c# code I'd like to know whether the app has been launched by the debugger (in my case VisualStudio). 
Does anyone know how to get this information?

TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached)

**Note:** The answer is not entirely correct. :)